# How can I tell which MacOS notarization tool is being used by the Maven plugin

Tags: maven, install4j

We have a build agent running on a Mac mini using version 10.0.6 of the install4j-maven plugin.

Up until recently we used the altool to perform notarization. I have confirmed that notarytool is now available on the machine, but cannot see any way to verify that this is being used from the logging that the plugin provides.

Is there any way to check which tool is actually being used?

I ran a build which triggered notarization (which succeeded). I was expecting some indication of which tool was used to achieve this, but nothing appeared in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Since install4j 10.0.5, notarytool is used if it is available. There is no logging output that indicates this.